# panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

Tags: go, slice

For the below code:

```
func Insert(m []Bucket, key string, value float64) {

    bucketNumber := (key[0] - 'A') / 7

    if cap(m[bucketNumber]) == 0 {
        m[bucketNumber] = make([]Entry, 0, 100)
    }

    var bucketFull bool
    bucketFull = len(m[bucketNumber]) == cap(m[bucketNumber])

    if bucketFull {

        m[bucketNumber] = append(m[bucketNumber], Entry{key, value})
    } else {

        m[bucketNumber][emptyPosition[bucketNumber]] = Entry{key, value}
    }
    emptyPosition[bucketNumber]++
}
```

---

`m[bucketNumber][emptyPosition[bucketNumber]] = Entry{key, value}` gives error

> panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0`

despite `m[bucketNumber] = make([]Entry, 0, 100)`

Why an assignment fails with runtime error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make([]Entry, 0, 100)` creates a slice that will have length 0 and capacity 100. The index must be less than the length.

So if the length is `0`, even index `0` is out of range.

If you want to create a slice with 100 elements, use

```
make([]Entry, 100, 100)
```

Or simply

```
make([]Entry, 100)
```

The 3rd parameter–the capacity–is used to reduce future allocations when you append elements to the slice.

If you do want to create your slice with 0 length, use the builtin `append()` function to add elements to the slice, e.g.:

```
s := make([]int, 0, 10)
s = append(s, 1)
```

**Your specific problem:**

```
bucketFull = len(m[bucketNumber]) == cap(m[bucketNumber])
```

This only checks if the length is equal to the capacity. For a newly allocated slice (with `make([]Entry, 0, 100)`) this will be obviously `false` (`0` does not equal to `100`), but this does not mean you can assign to an element of the slice. As mentioned, the index must be less than the length.

This `bucketFull` property only tells if new element can be added to the slice without reallocation. Adding new element may be achieved using the builtin `append()`, or reslicing the slice using the builtin `append()` or with a slice expression.

Read blog posts to get to know slices and arrays:

[The Go Blog: Go Slices: usage and internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro)

[The Go Blog: Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: `make([]Entry, 100, 100)` allocates equivalent memory as `make([]Entry, 0, 100)`  for backing array. Only difference is, In the later case, length field in slice header does not allow access to backing array. isn't it?

Comment: @overexchange Yes, that's right. The latter does not allow access to the elements of the backing array, not without reslicing it.